# Changing bool on this from inside lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, unreal-engine4

I have a bool on a AActor, that I'd like to change from a lambda function, how shall I capture the bool so it is actually changed? I currently use [&], which should pass this by reference as I understand it, however changing the bool from inside the lambda function doesn't change it on the actor.

```
[&] () { bMyBool = true; };
```

EDIT 1: more info

bool is defined in the header of the class as protected.

```
protected:
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, VisibleAnywhere)
    bool bMagBoots;
```

I have a function to bind a delegate to an input action, that should call the lambda.

```
void ASPCharacterActor::BindLambdaToAction(UInputComponent* InputComponent, FName ActionName,
EInputEvent InputEventType, TFunctionRef<void()> ActionHandler)
{
    FInputActionHandlerSignature ActionHandlerSignature;
    ActionHandlerSignature.BindLambda(ActionHandler);

    FInputActionBinding ActionBinding = FInputActionBinding(ActionName, InputEventType);
    ActionBinding.ActionDelegate = ActionHandlerSignature;
    InputComponent->AddActionBinding(ActionBinding);
}
```

Then I call the function inside BeginPlay. The lambda gets called when I press the button, however the bool won't change outside the lambda function. If I print it out inside the lambda it did change, so I think it just gets copied instead of referenced.

```
void ASPCharacterActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    BindLambdaToAction(InputComponent, "MagBoots", IE_Pressed, [&]
    {
        bMagBoots = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: You will need to show a [mre] that shows your unexpected behavior.  [As you can see here](https://godbolt.org/z/G9WKWEYcq), changing the bool in your lambda **does** affect the bool outside the lambda.

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that the OP is not _calling_ the lambda :-)

Comment: @andreee I expect the same :-)

Comment: Sadly I am calling it, I can even print out the bool inside the lambda function and it's set just not reflected on the actor. I think it might be unreal engine related thing. I don't think I can reproduce it outside of the unreal engine environment, I can post the actual implementation though if that would help.

Comment: Actually upon further testing the bMyBool value inside the lambda doesn't even correspond to the actor class. it's set to false in init and inside the lambda function it is true for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you have done, but your code will do what we expect by using the following environment around your single code line:

```
int main()
{
    bool bMyBool = false;

    auto l= [&] () { bMyBool = true; };
    l();
    std::cout << bMyBool << std::endl;
}
```

And as in your edit mentioned, you use it in a class context:

```
// Same in class context:
class X
{
    private:
        bool bMyBool = false;
        std::function<void(void)> lam; 
    public:

        void CreateAndStoreLambda() 
        {
            lam= [&] () { bMyBool = true; };
            // or you can capture this to access all vars of the instance like:
            // lam= [this] () { bMyBool = true; };
        }

        void CallLambda()
        {
            lam();
            std::cout << bMyBool << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    X x; 
    x.CreateAndStoreLambda();
    x.CallLambda();
}
```

[see it running](https://godbolt.org/z/8hcdfE1Yc)

Comment: Just a small addition: It is generally preferable to capture `bMyBool` explicitly.

Comment: @andreee: In this case especially not cause I want to show that the original line of OP works!

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: Interestingly if I use [&bMyBool] I can't access the variable at all.

Comment: @JacklinHeirdom: Update for class context

Comment: Thanks at least I know I am using it right. Sadly it doesn't work inside unreal engine or at least not in my use case for some reason. There is a lot of under the hood stuff added to the stock cpp so who knows what's really happening. I can do it a differently, I would just like to know why it doesn't work :(

Comment: @JacklinHeirdom Maybe you generate a copy of your instances somewhere and missed to regenerate the lambda to the copied object?

Comment: Actually the engine takes care of initialization and garbage collection (UE has that added) of the class, you just kinda work in the framework that does it's own thing, so that should be ok. Think it's probably related to the system that calls it. Ironically even though it's one of the best game engines it has a pretty bad documentation including only the most basic stuff. Might have to snoop in the source files what FInputActionHandlerSignature FInputActionBinding actually does under the hood.

Comment: @JacklinHeirdom "so that should be ok." ??? "care of initialization and garbage collection " that sounds it copies objects around. If so, take care of copy/move operators/constructors!

Comment: Weird thing is when I print out the boolean inside the lambda without changing it it says it's true, but I initialize the boolean to false and don't set it anywhere else.

Comment: Hmm looks like things get copied around a lot "As a reference you are at the mercy of whoever owns the memory. The object could be very transient - such as on the stack during program flow, or fairly transient - for instance in unreal's memory management system but wherever it is if you don't have control of the object and it's memory you want to pass by value rather than reference." Similar issue https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/537330/index.html